# Вопрос по АТС

Tags: база-данных, железо

подскажите самый адекватный вариант решения задачи: нужно определить номер входящего звонка, чтобы впоследствии передавать его в БД и показывать на экран информацию по клиенту (в таблице в БД первичным ключом как раз будет номер телефона).

Comment: Куда приходит звонок?

Comment: на экран кому

Comment: клиент звонит на сотовый телефон. Номер определяется и передается в базу данных на экран компьютера менеджера. В базе данных осуществляется поиск клиента по телефону(если до этого он уже обращался)

Answer (score 1):

АТС передает номер, в базе он сравнивается по АОНу с уже имеющимися в базе. Вроде как так и делают.